# Get top 10 most recent updated or created records from a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST_A` (
`test_a_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`added_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`added_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`test_a_id`)
);
```

I need to form a MYSQL query to get the most recent records that was either create or updated. What i have tried to do is write a sql query with order by clause on added_date and modified_date with desc like this

```
Select * from TEST_A order by added_date desc, modified_date desc limit 10;
```

but this gives me records in sequence of most recent added_date first and then most recent modified_date which is incorrect for me

How it should work is if i modify or add a record then that should be the first in the list. One solution that comes to my mind is to compare the modified_date and added_date with the current system date and arrange them accordingly, but this kind of query would be very slow if i have to display records without specifying any limit. basically i am using this type of query in my search functionality.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Change the sequence of added_date and modified_date, like this: `SELECT * FROM TEST_A ORDER BY modified_date desc, added_date desc LIMIT 10;`

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this:

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(added_date, modified_date) DESC LIMIT 10
```

With proper indexes, it should still be quite ok. If this is a huge table, then you might be better off with the solution offered by [KernelM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873982/521799) here

Answer (score 2):

I would have modified_date set upon insert (to the same as added_date) so then you just need to order by modified_date.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TEST_A ORDER BY  modified_date DESC, added_date DESC  LIMIT 10; ?